# Paper.js mouse events not translating with canvas transforms

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, canvas, paperjs

For performance and aesthetic reasons, I am transforming a canvas with a Paper.js "drawing" in it with a CSS transform (rotation).  Basically, on scroll, the canvas rotates, with a transition-duration to smooth it out.

On top of that, my Paper.js paths have mouse events on them so that on hover they change color.  However, when the CSS transform is applied to the canvas, the mouse events "disappear," for lack of a better word, and they don't work.  I guess somewhere along the line, the CSS transform is working on the canvas drawn elements but is skipping over or applied differently on the mouse events created by Paper.js tied to my paths.  Is there any solution?

Comment: Please share a JSfiddle with us, so we can have a look at the code.
It's it unusual to use a CSS transform on a canvas, animating the drawing would probably be more easily (and you wouldn't have to worry about rotated mouse coordinates in your paper project).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have answered the same question here: https://github.com/paperjs/paper.js/issues/945

Answer (score 0):

paperjs is not aware of the CSS transforms so it cannot map the mouse events to the transformed positions of your shapes. If you need to use transforms you must use paperjs transforms: [transform](http://paperjs.org/reference/path/#transform-matrix). I believe this works for a layer.